# structure php data in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I've got a data schema like this:

```
cp
    id    te    su
    1     7     2
    2     7     1
    3     6     8

cl
    id    cp    st
    1     2     5
    2     2     6
    3     1     6

us
   id    na
   ..    ..
   5     Joe
   6     Mike
   7     Tina
   ..    ..
```

I want to run a php function `foo($te)` with `foo(7)` to output data like this from mySQL

```
[0]
    su: 1
    st_list:
        [0]
            id:6
            na:Mike
[1]
    su: 2
    st_list:
        [0]
            id:5
            na:Joe
        [1]
            id:6
            na:Mike
```

I want to know how best to do this. Right now I'm able to use JOINs, but the result looks like this

```
[0]
    su: 1
    st_id:6
    st_na:Mike
[1]
    su: 2
    st_id:5
    st_na:Joe
[3]
    su: 2
    id:6
    na:Mike
```

The `su:2` is repeated... obviously that isn't a problem in this example, the problem is that in the real thing that `su` represents a lot more data, that i'll be getting through "this" (whatever answer I choose) method.

**EDIT:**
I hope you understand what I'm asking... I know a lot of you guys are way more knowledgable in mySQL and development in general than me, so that's why i'm asking in such a plain (I HAVE THS----> WANT THIS) way, because I think if I asked any more specifically I would end up making assumptions about the way it should run). I want an effecient solution, because this data is being used to populate search results.

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're going to need to make these more descriptively named and you probably should have a more descriptive desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to loop over the results yourself and build the array in the format you want. MySQL can't give you the results in the nested format you want. Here's a rough draft (untested):

```
$su = 0;
$st_list = array();
$nested = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    if ($su != 0 && $row['su'] != $su) {
        $nested[] = compact('su', 'st_list');
    }

    if ($su != $row['su']) {
        $su = $row['su'];
        $st_list = array();
    }

    $st_list[] = array(
        'id' => $row['st_id'],
        'na' => $row['st_na'],
    );
}

$nested[] = compact('su', 'st_list');
```

**Edit:** Usually it's best to simply fetch all the results you want using a single SQL query. That is almost always the most efficient way to do it. But if it really matters to you (and this is a performance critical part of your application), the only way to know for sure is benchmark both methods. A lot depends on your database layout, number of rows, SQL indexes, etcetera.

Comment: I have to loop over the results to build the desired structure, but is it best for me to use JOINS to get ALL the data, and then filter through it, or should I use multiple queries and queries in loops to only 'fetch' the data that i'm going to be using (i.e. not fetch duplicate `su:2`'s

Comment: ok, thanks.. I wasn't sure between more data vs more hits but ultimately smaller data which tends to be more effecient... BONUS QUESTION (if you would): will there be any problems with me adding a `join on su = ___` b/c of the duplicate `su`'s? (if not then i'll probably do it this way)

Comment: I can't tell. It depends on your original SQL query that you haven't posted. My best guess is not (as long as you do an outer join, not an inner join). The reason is that you *want* the multiple `su` entries in your result set. Because the code I posted uses those to determine how to aggregate the nested array.

Comment: There is no problem having duplicated su's. Making a big query versus making several smaller ones is, generally, faster. The results are compressed for transmission, and you don't have the overhead of preparing every new query. Obvioulsy, the only good answer is the truth of real testing and benchmarking, but if I have to choose I bet for the big one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct us.id,na FROM cp
LEFT JOIN cl ON cp.su = cl.cp
LEFT JOIN us ON us.id = cl.st
where te = "7"
```

Does this provide the results you are looking for?

Alternately,

```
SELECT su,us.id,na FROM cp
LEFT JOIN cl ON cp.su = cl.cp
LEFT JOIN us ON us.id = cl.st
where te = "7"
ORDER BY su
```

Is closer to the formatting you asked for in your post.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can have something like these too...

```
function get_te($te)
{
    $qry = $this->db->get_where('cp', array('te' => $te));
    $raw_te = $qry->result_array();
    $te = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($i < count($raw_te))
    {
        $te[$i]['su'] = $raw_te[$i]['su'];
        $qry = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('cl')
                        ->join('us', 'us.id = cl.id')
                        ->where('cp', $raw_te[$i]['id'])
                        ->get();
        $te[$i]['st_list'] = $qry->result_array();
        $i++;
    }
    return $te;
}
```